# How to set 'data is not found' in the html table if the data in the database is null?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, html-table

I am using Laravel 5 and I have a page which have some tables. My problem is, when there is no data in database, it shows nothing. I want it show 'Data is not found'. This first picture below is when the data is available in the database, and the second picture is when the data is unavailable in the database.

1.
[image]

2.

[image]

This is my code:

```
@if($candidateskill != '')
    @foreach($candidateskill as $getData)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $getData->SKILL_NAME }}</td>
      <td align="center">{{ $getData->SKILL_LEVEL }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
@else
    <td>Data is Not Found</td>
    <td>Data is Not Found</td>
@endif
```

And this is the output of the null data:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] =>
>   Array ( ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@forelse` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops)

```
@forelse($candidateskill as $getData)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $getData->SKILL_NAME }}</td>
        <td align="center">{{ $getData->SKILL_LEVEL }}</td>
    </tr>
@empty
    <tr><td colspan="2">No Data</td></tr>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@if($candidateskill && !$candidateskill->isEmpty())
@foreach($candidateskill as $getData)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $getData->SKILL_NAME }}</td>
      <td align="center">{{ $getData->SKILL_LEVEL }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach

@else
<tr>
<td>Data is Not Found</td>
</tr>
@endif
```

You need to evaluate your database variable if it exists, and if its not empty aka null.